# JavaScript wait for dynamic modules in Jest tests

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

Q: How can I wait for all my dynamic modules to be finished before my assertions in Jest ?

Scenario:

```js
// normal code
export default {
  a() {
     import('b', () => {
        window.hello = 'there'
     })
  }
}
```

```js
// test
import normalCode from 'normalCode'
it('should add to window', () => {
  normalCode.a()
  expect(window.hello).toBe('there')
})
```

The execution of the code above is:

1. runs `normalCode.a()`
2. runs `expect(window.hello).toBe('there')`
3. import finished and is running  `window.hello = 'there'`
4. it fails because assertions were wrong at step 2, but they would pass after step 3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to return the `import` promise from function `a`.

```js
// normal code
export default {
  a() {
     return import('b', () => {
        window.hello = 'there'
     })
  }
}
```

Then `await` it in your test.

```js
// test
import normalCode from 'normalCode'
it('should add to window', async () => {
  await normalCode.a()
  expect(window.hello).toBe('there')
})
```